Use COPY in PostgreSQL to insert huge amount of data to one table and populate another table at the same time using IDs
I have the following 2 tables in my database:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS segments (
        id SERIAL,
        segment TEXT NOT NULL,
        lang_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES languages(id),
        is_source BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        hash UUID NOT NULL,
        date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        date_modified TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY(id, hash),
        UNIQUE(segment, hash)
) PARTITION BY hash(hash);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pairs (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        src_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        tgt_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        src_file_id INTEGER REFERENCES documents(id),
        tgt_file_id INTEGER REFERENCES documents(id),
        src_hash UUID NOT NULL,
        tgt_hash UUID NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (src_id, src_hash) REFERENCES segments(id, hash),
        FOREIGN KEY (tgt_id, tgt_hash) REFERENCES segments(id, hash),
        UNIQUE (src_id, tgt_id)
);

The segments table contains strings from two parallel files, where each line in one file is semantically linked to the corresponding line in the other file.
When I do single INSERTs, I first insert the string from the one file, use ON CONFLICT and RETURNING ID to get the new or the existing id, then insert the corresponding string from the other file and do the same. This way I always get the 2 ids needed to INSERT into the pairs table.
Using single inserts for hundreds of millions of records is simply impossible as it takes forever to insert just a few million records. Using COPY is super fast and seems the only way to do it, but then I don't know what approach I could follow in order to get the required ids, insert in parallel to the pairs table, deal with the constraints, etc.
